# Azure File storage validate file after upload before deleting local copy

Tags: c#, azure, file, blob

We are migrating data to Azure file storage and want to validate the upload after it is complete before deleting the file from the local server.

Code below works fine, but I'm a little unclear from the docs on how to validate the file afterwards.

I was going to compare the byte count, but it looked like using transactionalCRC would work but I can't seem to get it implemented

[MS Docs on CRC64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.shared.protocol.checksumoptions.usetransactionalcrc64?view=azure-dotnet-legacy#Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Shared_Protocol_ChecksumOptions_UseTransactionalCRC64)

```
        byte[] theFile = UploadHelper.GetFileAsByteArray(theUpload);

        CloudFile theCloudFile = rootDir.GetFileReference(theUpload.Name);
        Stream theMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(theFile);
        await theCloudFile.UploadFromStreamAsync(theMemoryStream);
```

Or if I'm overthinking this and there is a better way I'd appreciate the insight.

Thank you,

Comment: If you have a backup I wouldn't do anything more. Provided Azure responds with a '201' result you can be confident it was successful. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44395881/how-to-check-whether-azure-blob-storage-upload-was-successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question as to how to validate the integrity of a file has a popular, accepted answer here:

[Calculate MD5 checksum for a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520048/calculate-md5-checksum-for-a-file)

Comment: And how does this help when the file is on Azure? Also, if the question is a duplicate, mark it as such, don't post an answer.

Comment: @Patrick, so I calculate a hash of the local and remote files, if they're the same I can trust the validity of the upload?  It seemed like the transactionalCRC check was something that could be done as part of the upload.

Comment: @RobertSullivan I think you can trust the upload if the hashes are the same

Comment: Test it out using Beyond Comapre